# Paypal Embedded Flow - POP window blocked

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, popup-blocker

I have successfully integrated Paypal Embedded Chained Adaptive Payment system.

I have been testing it in sandbox environment. On GOOGLE Chrome, when user initiates the payment procedure, a light box gets opened with a login button inside it, but once user clicks on that login button, user comes across with following message

"Please continue with your purchase in the secure browser we launched. If you don't see it, click on Go."

The reason for this is that Chrome blocks the paypal login pop-up window. End user would not be able to figure out that what happened. Most of end users would not be  aware about that paypal login pop-up window being blocked. Can we do something here so that we can avoid that pop-up window and can perform whole operation inside the Iframe only ?

Is there any solution this problem ?
Will it get resolved automatically once we shall move to production/live environment?

Please help me out.. We are going live very soon!!

Comment: Why paypal support is silent ?

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing around with this a lot today and I too encountered the same issue with the lightbox. HOWEVER after much fiddling and time I decided to just try expType="mini" and it worked flawlessly. I did find one site that managed to get chrome to display the lightbox method correctly, but it was only successful about half of the time. It seems chrome is very sensitive to popups and sometimes it can be fooled and sometimes not.

Anyway the solution I found that worked was to scrap expType=lightbox and just go with expType=mini - seems to work without any problems. In the back of my mind I'm a little concerned that future browser releases (in particular chrome) will have updated popup blocking code may soon block this too. I hope this remains working, but I don't have a great deal of confidence in it. Make sure you have the good old Express Checkout method as a backup.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Actually I already tried that but it does not work in different versions of chrome on various OS..